# How to return ROW_NUMBER() with sorted database results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, jdbc, row-number

Good Evening, I currently study the `ROW_NUMBER()` in **squirrel sql**. I success to retrieve data from the database, but the problem is the R in the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS R` does not match with the sorted database data. Need some suggestion and hints for the query below, thanks

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECORDS  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS R,
somethingAisID, somethingB, somethingC ORDER BY somethingA ) AS T WHERE R>=0
AND R<=100
```

p/s: The database rows is sorted, but the R fields is match with the un-sorted database rows.

Example:

the `somethingAisID` which sorted from the query is 1,2,3,4,5

the `somethingAisID` which un-sorted from the original database table is 4,5,2,3,1

then the R is match as 4,5,2,3,1

How can I query the R to match as 1,2,3,4,5? (sorted query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ORDER BY` in `OVER` clause for that

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name [ASC|DESC]) AS R
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8460d/3)** demo

Comment: Feature not implemented: WINDOW/ORDER BY.

Is this the sql error or is my squirrel is not up to date?

thanks

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server ?) are you using and what version?

Comment: squirrel-sql-3.1.2, GlassFishESBv22, does this is the info you want?

Comment: No, not that. What database management system are you using/connecting to with sqirrel if you wish (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, Postgres,...)?

Comment: So what is it? Take a look at a driver you use in SQuirreL to define a connection.

Comment: So I guess it is SQL Server. If so try it with SQL Server Management Studio not from squirrel client and see sqlfiddle example that I've provided.